# How to add some html during post-link phase in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How does one add a pure html fragment during a post link phase in directive? I am able to locate the element that I want to add to, just don't know which method or how to add it. Is it appendChild or insertAdjacentHTML or something else?

I am trying to add indicator that field is required in a label

Here is html

```
 <label id="street">{{addressName}} Address:</label>
```

Here is what I have in a link function

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, model) {
  var addressLabel = element[0].querySelector("#street");
  // add this to label("<sup>*</sup>");
}
```

How can I add fragment `<sup>*</sup>` into label element?

Update:

Based on Samir's comment here is how it looks right now

```
   (function (angular) {
        'use strict';

        angular
            .module('app')
            .directive('srAddressEditor',srAddressEditor);

        srAddressEditor.$inject = [$compile];

        function srAddressEditor($compile) {

            var controllerId = 'addressEditCtrl';
            var controller = ['$scope', '$q', "addressEditDataSvc", "lodash", addressEditCtrl];

            var directive = {
                require: '?ngModel',
                templateUrl: '/app/shared/addressEditor/addressEdit.html',
                scope: {
                    address: '=',
                    addressName: '@',
                    requiredFields: '@' // comma delimited list of required fields street,zipCode,city,stateCode,countryCode
                },
                //compile: compile,
                link: link,
                controller: controller
            };

            return directive;

            function link(scope, element, attrs, model) {

                var requiredFields = (scope.requiredFields || "");

                if (requiredFields != "") {
                    requiredFields = requiredFields.split(",");
                } else {
                    requiredFields = [];
                }

                requiredFields.forEach(function (fieldName) {
                    var label = element[0].querySelector("#lbl_" + fieldName);
                    label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML + "<sup class='req'>*</sup>";
                });
        var compiled = $compile(element[0].innerHTML)(scope);
        element.replaceWith(compiled);
        element = compiled;
            }

            function addressEditCtrl($scope, $q, addressEditDataSvc, lodash) {
        }
//bunch of code
        }
    })(angular);
```

Comment: `addressLabel.innerHTML = addressLabel.innerHTML+ '<sup>*</sup>';`

Comment: @Samir: Greate that works, as long as there is no binding in label, but if I do something like this  <label id="lbl_street">{{addressName}} Address:</label>, then it throws an interpolation error in the background. I guess I need to compile new html ?

Comment: Yes you can use $compile service like `label.innerHTML = $compile('<label id="lbl_street">{{addressName}} Address:</label>')(scope);`

Comment: @Samir: I added 3 lines to the end of the link function. Now it bind s addressName correctly but I still have error in the back at at interpolateFnWatchAction (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.js:8018:17)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be create a directive just for the `label`

For example

**Javascript (angular)**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myLabelDirective', function() {

   return {
      link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.addressName = 'Some address name';
       scope.addition = '*';
      },
      template : '<label id="street">{{addressName}} Address:  <sup>{{addition}}</sup></label>'
   };

});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <my-label-directive></my-label-directive>
</body>
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach for what you want, but I think it's kind easier and cleaner than just appending the text you want to append.

Here's the plunker in case you want to see it http://plnkr.co/edit/YP0AXtcx3GiBDbYPNKkp?p=preview